# Extract Angular components to plain HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have an angular app that I need to use as a source of the components for my new app that will be mostly using pure HTML. I need to get the HTML and CSS from the Angular app.

The problem is, that the app uses custom components such as `<mat-icon>` that are not standard HTML tags. I assume, that under the hood they eventually consist of simple HTML elements but I can't figure it out. Is there any method to convert an Angular website to plain HTML & CSS? I know that the dynamic content can't be extracted, but I mean only the view. Maybe there is a Chrome extension to do that? I do have access to the app source code, so it can be also some npm module.

Comment: Maybe you can use scully.io to render the site? That outputs plain html..